# MUI extending button props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I want to extend the MUI5 components and also use their `component` prop. To do that according to the [documentation](https://mui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop) I make it work in the below code:

```js
import Button, { ButtonProps } from '@mui/material/Button';
import React from 'react';

export type MyButtonProps<C extends React.ElementType> = ButtonProps<C, { component?: C }> & {
  myOtherField: string;
};

export function MyButton<C extends React.ElementType>(props: MyButtonProps<C>) {
  const { myOtherField, ...buttonProps } = props;
  return <Button {...buttonProps}></Button>;
}
```

However when I try to access anything belongs to MUI5 button attributes, vscode is not helping me to find it
see the below screenshot:
[image]

But after adding it manually it is not complaining about it.
see the below screenshot and check that it is inferring the type as `any`

[image]

However if I remove the `<C extends React.ElementType>` logic from the type it is working like a charm (but it has a drawback since it is now complaining about the `component` prop when I use it anywhere in my application):

[image]

What can be the problematic part in the first place when I am extending MUI5 button prop types?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This is the easy way I found for your usecase:

```
type NewButtonProps = ButtonProps & {
  otherField: number;
  component: React.ElementType;
};

function Button3({ otherField, ...props }: NewButtonProps) {
  const y = props.onClick;
  const x = otherField;

  return <Button {...props}></Button>;
}
```

All the attributes is understand by typescript now:

[image: work example]

Comment: No actually, this doesn't solve my problem since it is lack of the solution about the `component` attribute which is the whole point. when I extend the button in your way I am getting type errors from the `component` attribute. 

          <MyNewButton variant="text" component={Link} to="/" color="primary">
                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

`
  Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: "inherit" | "primary" | ... 5 more ... | undefined; .`

Comment: you can check the component prop usage from here: https://mui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop

Comment: I edit my answer. You just need to add the component props yourself. It's not the best way but this fix your problem

Comment: That also doesn't work since it should be extended by the component attributes which I put there. For example, as you can see from my previous comment when I use `router Link` as the `component`, button should have `to` attribute also. I can do it by adding this attribute to button props also but as you said it is not a good solution.

Comment: Can you add a codesandbox to try it myself ?